# Rule of inference for proof by contradiction.

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

In the book "Discrete Mathematical Structures" - Kolman, author has stated that **proof by contradiction** is based on the tautology ((p⇒q)∧(~q))⇒(~p).And that this argument form is often applied to the case where q is an absurdity.
But this tautology is modus tollens.

In another text-book rule of inference for proof by contradiction is :

```
          ~p⇒c, where c is contradiction.
          ∴p
```

Please help me understand how rule of inference for proof by contradiction is modus tollens or based on above tautology. And what is the relation between two rules of inference?

Comment: I believe the intended meaning of "contradiction" in the block quote is actually "absurdity" (false). You simply replace $q$ in your first formula with $\neg c$.

Comment: You might also want to read the post [proof by contradiction, vs. proof by contrapositive](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262828/proof-by-contradiction-vs-prove-the-contrapositive/262831#262831).

Answer (score 4):

"Proof by contradiction" is, I take it, another label for the Reductio rule which can helpfully be displayed as

$$\quad\quad | \quad A$$
$$\quad\quad | \quad \vdots$$
$$\quad\quad | \quad C$$
$$\quad\quad | \quad \vdots$$
$$\quad\quad | \quad \neg C$$
$$\neg A$$

or (in another formulation)

$$\quad\quad | \quad A$$
$$\quad\quad | \quad \vdots$$
$$\quad\quad | \quad \bot$$
$$\neg A$$

When $A$ is a temporary assumption, which (via some subproof) leads to an explicit contradition or an absurdity $\bot$, we are allowed to discharge that temporary assumption and conclude (from whatever other premisses are in play) that it must be false, $\neg A$.

This is a valid rule of inference in systems of logic which lack a conditional (and even where a conditional can't be defined). So it is unhelpful -- to say the least -- to say that is "based on" a tautology involving a conditional (or on modus tolens).

If you do have reductio and modus ponens that modus tollens will be a derived rule:

$$A \to C$$
$$\neg C$$
$$\quad\quad | \quad A$$
$$\quad\quad | \quad C$$
$$\quad\quad | \quad \bot$$
$$\neg A$$

And conversely, if you have a conditional proof rule for introducing conditionals, modus tollens, and the assumption $\neg\bot$ then you could get reductio as a derived rule.

> But, to repeat, it would be wrong to say that the result that (with a bit of help) you can get reductio from modus tollens is what "really" underlies reductio. Reductio is a warranted inferential rule because of the meaning of negation, not (even in part) because of the meaning of the conditional.

That, as they say, is the take-home message!

Comment: Do any of the standard packages for proof-layout Fitch-style (*fitch.sty*) or Gentzen-style (*bussproofs.sty*) work here? I'm assuming not ... but I'm unclear what the best cheat for such things is!

Comment: PeterSmith: good question. It would be nice if someone can answer your question. I'd like to know, too!

Answer (score 4):

The thing you're missing is the law of non-contradiction:

$$ \neg (P \wedge \neg P) $$

i.e. $\neg c$ when $c$ is a contradiction.

To perform a proof by contradiction -- proving $\neg p$ via a proof of $p \implies c$ -- via proof by contrapositive, let $q$ be $c$.

The form of proof by contradiction you quote follows from the form I mention above by the equivalence $\neg \neg p \equiv p$. (so substitute $\neg p$ into your proof by contrapositive)