# Euclid's proof that they are infinity prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-explanation

**Euclid's** proof that they are **infinity prime numbers** look more as a statement then a proof for me. For thing to be even worse, it's example used every time to show the basic proof you can find. If I have understood it good, in nutshell proof is:

*If this is a prime number it’s good, and we have a new one:*

```
        N = (p0 · p1 · p2 · … · pn)
```

*If not, adding 1 we will create a new one:*

```
        N = (p0 · p1 · p2 · … · pn)+1
```

*Example:*

Let’s imagen we know only for first two primes 3 and 5. With this formula

```
        N = 3·5 = 15 (15 is not prime, you can divide it with 3 and 5)

        N = (3·5)+1 = 16 (it’s not prime)
```

What I doing wrong?

Here is [explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1731387/understanding-euclids-proof-that-the-number-of-primes-is-infinite) already given, but can someone do relation between actual explanation and example i posted.

Comment: I don't believe you have understood the argument.  $\prod p_i$ is clearly not prime.

Comment: No, you have not correctly understood the proof.

Comment: See Euclid's theorem]([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem#Euclid.27s_proof): the proof is different.

Comment: Ok, can you give me some good referials where i can get clear understandung of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument is the following. Suppose you have already $n$ primes $p_{1}, \dots, p_{n}$.

Then
$$
A = p_{1} \cdot p_{2} \cdots p_{n} + 1 > 1
$$
is not divisible by $p_{1}, \dots, p_{n}$, as Euclidean division by any of them yields remainder $1$.

Since every natural number greater than $1$ is a product of primes, there must be a prime $p$, distinct from $p_{1}, \dots, p_{n}$, which divides $A$.

In your case, you have taken $n = 2$, $p_{1} = 3$, $p_{2} = 5$. You get $A = 16$, and the only choice for $p$ is $2$.

Had you taken $n = 2$, $p_{1} = 5$ and $p_{2} = 7$, then $A = 36$ so you have either $p = 2$ or $p = 3$.

Comment: "Since every natural number greater than is a product of primes" - key,  thanks!