# Prove if m + n ≥ 59 then (m ≥ 30 or n ≥ 30) by Contraposition

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need help with this contraposition.

**Question**
Let m, n ≥ 0 be integers. Prove that
if m + n ≥ 59 then (m ≥ 30 or n ≥ 30).

**What I've done so far**

I'm not exactly sure if I am setting this up right. Since my I am using proof by contraposition I am setting it up as.

m, n ≤ 0
If m + n ≤ 59 then (m ≤ 30 or n ≤ 30).

I don't know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Try a proof by contradiction. That means assume that the statement you want to prove is false, then work logically and correctly to show that some false statement is made true.

Comment: @FarazMasroor The question requires a proof by contraposition, not contradiction - there is a technical difference: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262828/proof-by-contradiction-vs-prove-the-contrapositive

Answer (score 1):

That's not the contrapositive.

Instead try:

IF $(m<30)$ AND $(n<30)$ THEN $(m+n < 59)$.

(Remember you're dealing with integers here).

Answer (score 0):

If $p\implies q$ then the contrapositive of it is $\neg\ q\implies \neg p$ and those two statements are equivalent.

Applying it to this case, we have to prove that if $m<30 \land n<30$ then $m+n<59.$

However, this is obvious so we have proved the first statement by contraposition.

QED.