# How to prove the statement directly: if $mn$ is odd, then both $m, n$ are odd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can this be proved directly?

> If $mn$ is odd, then both $m$ and $n$ are odd.

My homework is telling me to prove this directly, but I believe a  direct proof doesn't exist. Obviously this is an easy proof by contrapositive.

Comment: prime decomposition?

Comment: Is presenting the $4$ cases and showing that "$mn$ odd" only occurs in one case a direct proof ?

Comment: $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$ is field.

Comment: Don't know what it is meant by "directly". Possibly,  that if you write $n=2k_n+j_n$ with $j_n=0,1$, and analogously for $m$ and multiply, you will get that for the result to be odd it must be $j_n j_m=1$ .

Comment: Both $m$ and $n$ divide $mn$. Since $mn$ is odd, it only has odd primes in its factorization, which means only products of odd primes can divide it.

Answer (score 6):

By Division Algorithm, if we divide $m$ and $n$ by $2$, we have $m=2p+r$ and $n=2q+s$ with $0\leq r,s <2$.  Then $r$ and $s$ are $0$ or $1$, so $rs = 0$ or $1$.  Then $mn = (2p+r)(2q+s) = 2(2pr +ps+qr) + rs$.  Since $mn$ is odd, $rs$=1.
So neither $r$ nor $s$ is $0$.  Therefore $r=s=1$ and so $m$ and $n$ are odd.

Comment: I don't really know what the setter of the OP's homework meant by "prove directly", but how are you "proving directly" that $rs = 1$ implies neither $r$ nor $s$ is $0$?

Comment: If $rs=1$, then $r$ and $s$ are both units in the ring $Z$.  Since they're positive, they're both equal to one.

Comment: @B.Goddard That method presumably depends on a lemma that $\,0\,$ is not a unit (in a nonzero ring), which probably doesn't count as "direct" (i.e. hiding the indirect part in a lemma does not eliminate it).

Answer (score 1):

If by contrapositive you mean contradiction you can simply state:

Every multiple of 2 is divisible by 2.

If you mean that you can only work with odd numbers I'd consider the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. With this you can notice that multiplication carries over the original prime factors thus yielding an odd number.

Comment: No, a proof by contrapositive ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition)) and a proof by contradiction ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction)) are different. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262828/proof-by-contradiction-vs-prove-the-contrapositive

Comment: Oh ok, right, I only saw it called modus tollens. nice to refresh that ol' stuff. :-)