# Closed subsets of compact sets are compact (original proof)

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, compactness

> Baby Rudin Theorem 2.35: Suppose $F \subset K \subset X$ where $X$ a metric space. Suppose $F$ closed relative to $K$ and  $K$ compact. Then $F$ is compact.

This is my original attempt to prove this theorem.

Here, Rudin's definitions are :

- $p$ is a *limit point* of a subset of a metric space iff every neighborhood(defined in terms of open balls) of $p$ contains a point in the subset which is not equal to $p$
- Subsets of metric spaces are *closed* iff it contains all its limit points.
- A point $p$ is an *interior point* of a subset of a metric space if there exists a neighborhood $N(p)$ of $p$ such that $N(p)$ is contained within the subset.
- Subsets of metric spaces are *open* iff all its points are interior points.
- Subsets of metric spaces are *compact* iff every open cover has a finite subcover.

Proof: Suppose $K$ compact and $F \subset K$ closed but not compact. Then there is a cover of $F$ which has no finite subcover say $S$. Let $G=\bigcup^{n}_{i=1}G_i$ be an open cover of $K$ which is finite. Define $M_i=G_i\cap F^c $ where $F^c$ complement of $F$. Then each $M_i$ is open since $G_i$ and $F^c$ are open. Now for any $x \in K$, either $x \in F$ or $x \in F^c$. If $x\in F$, then $x \in S_\alpha $ where $S_\alpha$ is an element of $S$. If $x \in F^c$ then $x \in G_i\cap F^c $ for some $i \in \mathbb{N}$ since $K \subset G$. So if $M=\bigcup^{n}_{i=1} M_i$, then $M \cup S$ is a cover of $K$. But then clearly, this cover has no finite subcover hence $K$ is not compact. $\square$

Comment: If $S$ is "a cover of $F$ which has no finite subcover", then the elements of $S$ are _subsets of $X$_. Later on, you write $x\in S$ which does not make any sense because $x$ is an _element_ of $X$, not a subset of it.

Comment: As a more high-level comment, using an indirect proof here is a definite detour. You can prove that $F$ is compact _directly_, by letting someone give you an open cover of $F$ and showing how to find a finite subcover of it, using the compactness of $K$.

Comment: I see. I believe Rudin's proof is something along that line but I always try to come up with an alternative proof and this was the first proof that came naturally to me.  Regarding $x$ not being an element of $S$, is the new edit enough to fix the problem?

Comment: That is a very good point if $M={X}\setminus F$, then $M\cup S$ is also a cover of $K$

Answer (score 5):

Your proof is hard to read, has deficiencies (see comment of Henning) and is needlessly complicated.

Here a way that is not contrapositive.

---

Let $\mathcal G$ be a collection of open sets that cover $F$.

Then $\mathcal G\cup\{F^{\complement}\}$ is a collection of open sets that covers $K$.

Since $K$ is compact there is a finite subcollection $\{G_1,\dots,G_n\}\cup\{F^{\complement}\}$.

From $F\subseteq K=\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^nG_i\right)\cup F^{\complement}$ it follows that $F\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^nG_i$ so apparantly  $\{G_1,\dots,G_n\}$ is a finite subcollection of $\mathcal G$ that covers $F$.

Proved is now that every collection of open sets that cover $F$ has a finite subcollection that covers $F$.

That comes to the same as: $F$ is compact.

Comment: This is verbatim the proof given by Rudin(although more readable) and I DO indeed like its simplicity but I believe its always useful to come up with an original proof without first having to look at the "perfect example".

Comment: That can never harm, and it is indeed useful on its own to try things out yourself. So I share in that belief :-).

Answer (score 3):

You're phrasing your proof as:

> Suppose $K$ is compact, *bla bla bla bla* hence $K$ is not compact.

This is the structure of a *proof by contradiction*, but your underlying idea is not really a proof by contradiction. In particular you're *never using* the assumption that $K$ is compact anywhere in the "bla bla bla bla" part. So what you really have is an argument that

> Assume $F$ is not compact. Then $K$ is not compact.

This is the *contrapositive* of the implication you wanted to show. Since every implication is logically equivalent to its contrapositive, this gives rise to a formally valid proof -- but pretending it is a proof-by-contradiction by tacking on a never-used assumption that $K$ is compact just makes it confusing and hard to follow. The reader keeps waiting for a place where the assumption is used, but it never comes.

Another point where your proof is needlessly complex is when you say "Let $G$ be an open cover of $K$ which is finite". There's no reason for you to parameterize your proof over an *arbitrary* open cover when instead you can just decide on a particular finite open cover of $K$ to use, namely setting $G=\{X\}$. Doing so would allow you to avoid a level of indices in the entire rest of the proof.

Actually I **suspect** these two points are connected: You may have thought that you need to assume that $K$ is compact before you can assert that it has a finite open cover. But that's not what compactness means -- *everything* has a finite open cover, namely $\{X\}$. Compactness means that the set has finite open covers *with special properties* (namely being subcovers of an *infinite* open cover you have thought up somehow), but you don't actually need those special properties in the argument you present.

Comment: I believe the reason I defied $G$ to be finite was that I was trying to lay out the definitions before tackling the problem and I failed to realise that it was a redundant condition. But I think in this case I'm not sure if I have to use the property that $K$ is compact.  Because what I essentially wanted to show was that if $F$ is not compact, then $K$ cannot be compact either which contradicts the assumption that $K$ was compact.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. It dives right in to the student's work and details all the misplaced assumptions and confused arguments, and explains how to fix them. It's a lot more work to write this up than to just give a corrected version of the argument. Nicely done.

Comment: This link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262828/using-proof-by-contradiction-vs-proof-of-the-contrapositive addresses the confusion with surrounding the difference between proof by contradiction and contrapositive with some very good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Refined proof:

Suppose $F$ not compact. Then there is a cover of $F$ which has no finite subcover say $S$. Define $M=\{X\}\setminus F$. Then $M \cup S$ is a cover of $K$. But then clearly, this cover has no finite subcover hence $K$ is not compact. $\square$

Comment: this is fine -- however i would argue little is gained in re-writing this. its very similar to rudin's proof in terms of using many of the same ideas/relationships. but writing a proof is still an exercise in itself i suppose!