# Hammack: Example 13.4 -- proof that there is no limit for sin(1/x) as x goes to 0

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-explanation

In section "13.3 Limits That Do Not Exist", of his "Book of Proof" (3rd Edition) Hammack gives:

> **Example 13.4** Prove that $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \sin\left({\frac{1}{x}}\right)$ does not exist.
>
> As $x$ approaches $0$, the number $\frac{1}{x}$ grows bigger, approaching infinity, so
> $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ just bounces up and down, faster and faster the closer $x$ gets to $0$.

His proof appears to be a direct proof that it is not true that there is a limit -- but it seems to start as if it is a proof by contradiction.  This bothers me because a "proof of the contrary" does not seem to be the same as "proof by contradiction".

Here is the proof as given:

> **Proof.** Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \sin\left({\frac{1}{x}}\right) = L$ for $L \in \mathbb{R}$.
> Definition 13.2 guarantees a number $\delta$ for which $0 < |x - 0| < \delta)$ implies $|\sin\left({\frac{1}{x}}\right) - L| < \frac{1}{4}$.  Select $k \in \mathbb{N}$ large enough so that $\frac{1}{k\pi} < \delta$.  As $0 < \left|\frac{1}{k\pi} - 0\right| < \delta$, we have $\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{1/k\pi}\right)-L\right| < \frac{1}{4}$, and this yields $\left|\sin\left(k\pi\right)-L\right| = \left|0-L\right| = \left|L\right|< \frac{1}{4}$.
>
> Next, take $l \in \mathbb{N}$ large enough so that $\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} + 2l\pi} < \delta$, so we have $0 < \left|\frac{1}{k\pi} - 0\right| < \delta$, we have $\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} + 2l\pi}}\right)-L\right| < \frac{1}{4}$, which simplifies to $\left|\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2l\pi\right)-L\right| = \left|1-L\right| < \frac{1}{4}$.
>
> Above we showed $\left|L\right|< \frac{1}{4}$ and $\left|1-L\right| < \frac{1}{4}$. Now apply the inequality (13.2) to get the contradiction $1 < \frac{1}{2}$, as $1 = |L+(1-L)| \le |L| + |1-L| < \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Hammack also gives:

> ... in symbolic form Definition 13.2 says $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$
> if and only if
>
> $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, (0 < |x - c| < \delta) \implies (|f(x) - L| < \epsilon)$          (13.4)

I believe the contrary of that is:

$\exists \epsilon > 0, \forall \delta > 0, (0 < |x - c| < \delta) \land \lnot(|f(x) - L| < \epsilon)$

So the above proof appears to prove the contrary.  It chooses an $\epsilon$ and shows that for all $\delta$ it is not true that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$, no matter what value of $L \in \mathbb{R}$ might be.  Proving the last part is by contradiction: it is proved that assuming $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ is true (for all $\delta$ and all $L$) leads to a contradiction.

So my actual questions are:

1. perhaps I have misread Hammack, and all his proofs of the non-existence of limits are indeed (implicitly) direct proofs of not-existence (proof of the contrary), but the last *step* of that is generally a proof by contradiction ?

Or:

2. perhaps I am mistaken in thinking that "proof of the contrary" and "proof by contradiction" are different ?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you're confused about, but this is a classic application of proof by contradiction. The author shows that if we assume there does in fact exist a limit, then we arrive at the contradiction $1< \frac{1}{2}$. Since this is nonsensical, there cannot exist such a limit in the first place.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, by "proof of contrary" you mean proof of negation, in which case you're right; a proof of negation is different from a proof by contradiction. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262828/using-proof-by-contradiction-vs-proof-of-the-contrapositive and the comments therein.

Comment: @JLinsta: trying to be clear about my confusion :-)  The objective here is to prove "there is no limit".  As I have understood it (so far) a proof by contradiction would attempt to prove "there is a limit" and find that leads to a contradiction.  That would involve a proof $\forall \epsilon > 0$, where this proof starts with a carefully chosen $\epsilon = \frac{1}{4}$ -- which looks like a direct proof of "there is no limit" (which involves $\exists \epsilon > 0$), which is the contrary of "there is a limit".

Comment: @ChrisHall Ah I see there your confusion lies.

When we assume there exists a limit $L$, what we really mean is that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $$0 < |x| < \delta \Rightarrow |\sin(\frac{1}{x}) - L| < \epsilon.$$  In particular, if we choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{4}$, then there exists $\delta$ such that $$0 < |x| < \delta \Rightarrow |\sin(\frac{1}{x}) - L| < \frac{1}{4}.$$ The author is simply using the definition of limits to cook up this $\delta$. Then uses the property of this $\delta$ to derive a contradiction.

Comment: @ChrisHall The goal is not to prove that for $\epsilon > 0$, we can find a $\delta > 0$ satisfying $$0 < |x| < \delta \Rightarrow |\sin(\frac{1}{x}) - L| < \epsilon.$$ We are assuming that to be true when we assume $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ has a limit at $0$. Thus we must use that fact to get a contradiction. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JLinsta: I think part of my confusion is that the contradiction in the proof arises when considering two values of $1/x$ both $0 < |x| < \delta$ for the same (carefully chosen) $\epsilon$ and **also** for the same $\delta$ (which we know must exist for that $\epsilon$).  I kept thinking that for different values of $|x|$ we could assume different values of $\epsilon$ and different values of $\delta$, so that there would be no contradiction.  [It (now) seems to me that there is an implied **$\forall x$**, $0 < |x - c| < \delta$ in the definition of what is required for a limit to exist.]