# Questions about proofs

Tags: soft-question, education

To prove, e.g., the identity $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2$, I remembered working, in high school, in the following way. Expanding the LHS gives

\begin{equation}
(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=a^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2,\qquad(1)
\end{equation}

while, expanding the RHS gives

\begin{align}
(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2&=a^2c^2+b^2d^2+2acbd+a^2d^2+b^2c^2-2abcd\\
&=a^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2,    \qquad(2)
\end{align}

Comparing the RHS of (1) and (2) one deduces that $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2$.

**First question:** Is this considered an acceptable proof at a post-secondary level? Or should one work differently, like, for instance, by completing the square

\begin{align}
(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)&=a^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2=a^2c^2+a^2d^2-2abcd+b^2c^2+b^2d^2+2abcd\\
&=(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2
\end{align}

As another example consider the proof that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}<\sqrt{15}$. Teachers in secondary school (and even some lecturers in engineering schools I know) usually work like this:

- Taking the square of each side of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}<\sqrt{15}$  gives  $2+6+2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{6}<15$.
- Rearranging gives $2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{6}<7$.
- Squaring again gives $48<49$.
- Since $48<49$ then $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}<\sqrt{15}$.

Nevertheless, according to A Concise Introduction to Pure Mathematics of Martin Liebeck, previous argument is not a proof. Indeed, citing the author *We have shown that if P is the statement we want to prove, and Q is the statement that 48 < 49, then P⇒Q; but this tells us nothing about the truth or otherwise of P.*
The proper proof starts by supposing the veracity of the contrary
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}\geq\sqrt{15}
\end{equation}
We have then
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}\geq\sqrt{15}&\Rightarrow \left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}\right)^2\geq\left(\sqrt{15}\right)^2\Rightarrow 2+6+2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{6}\geq 15\\
&\Rightarrow 2\sqrt{12}\geq 7\Rightarrow 4\times 12\geq 49\Rightarrow 47\geq 48
\end{align*}
that is a contradiction.

**Second question:** Is this lack of rigor on the part of teachers justified?

Comment: From the description of the [tag:proof-writing] tag, *"This tag should not be the only tag for a question"*.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: @Shaun I apologize for my mistake. Could you please suggest to me some relevant tags? Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: If you follow the exact same procedure with $-(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6}) < -\sqrt{15}$, do you arrive at the same conclusion?  Should you?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly. Try the [tag:education] tag.

Comment: @Shaun Thanks again. I've posted the question in https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/ as suggested by the Education tag. I've also slightly modified my question here in order to be clear what my queries are.

Comment: 1. What you describe is what I would call "multiplying out and cancelling like terms". It is a perfectly good method of proof . 2. Your argument is valid if you replace $\Rightarrow$ by $\Leftrightarrow$ (but you then need to justify steps like $x < y \Leftrightarrow x^2 < y^2$ - which holds if $x$ and $y$ are non-negative). Presenting the argument starting from the conclusion makes it clearer how the proof was found.

Comment: Btw the first statement is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity and is proved more generally by considering the norm in the Gaussian integers is multiplicative.

Comment: @Dimitris: Better than in a comment, would be to link to all cross-posted copies of this question from within each question; e.g. "Crossposted to [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/24635)." Note that the link is to the question, not the main site page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first proof is good, and contains no structural problems whatsoever. If I were presenting it to kids who had just learned how to expand binomials, I might include extra steps. If I were including this in a research paper, I might skip some of these steps (possibly all of them!). But, unlike the second proof, this method of proof (manipulating one side of the proposed equation, then the other) is a perfectly valid way of proving an equality.

I agree with Liebeck about the second proof: it contains a fallacy known as "affirming the consequent". This is a very common problem in beginners' proofs, where it's often much easier to begin with the conclusion (as there's often more to simplify there) and work back to the premises. Here, there isn't really anything in the premises, but the conclusion, $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} < \sqrt{15}$, can be manipulated. You can see the temptation here!

Proving by contradiction, as Liebeck suggests, is one way to handle this. Another is to simply write the steps in reverse order! It is sufficiently obvious that $48 < 49$. If we take the square root of both sides (note: the square root function is strictly increasing, so it preserves even strict inequalities), then we get
$$2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{6} = \sqrt{48} < \sqrt{49} = 7.$$
Adding $8$ to both sides, this becomes
$$(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6})^2 = 2 + 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{6} < 15.$$
Once again, taking the square root of both sides, bearing in mind that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} \ge 0$, we get
$$\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} = \sqrt{(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6})^2} < \sqrt{15}.$$
And we are done!

It's the same steps, but written backwards, maybe with a little exposition in between. This is why, even though the teacher has committed a fallacy, it actually kinda works in the end. They've written a perfectly valid proof, just in the wrong order. The steps presented should have been in the teacher's scratch work, but when it came time to present the proof, they should have presented it as I did above.

That said, when teaching students about proofs, it's sometimes (often?) not a good idea to present only the polished, finished proof, and this is a perfect example of why. Imagine you're in the class, the teacher claimed that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} < \sqrt{15}$, and then said "It is sufficiently obvious that $48 < 49$....". You would spend the whole time trying to figure out how the teacher pulled this inequality out of thin air, and it tells you nothing about how the teacher actually figured out how to prove this in the first place.

So, it's sometimes better that a teacher presents a proof that's less than perfect. And, given time constraints, it's sometimes not possible that they also present the finished product. So, for that reason, I'd say it is justified, for a teacher under time pressure, to present a proof like this. I would just hope that they would also explain to their students that this is the scratchwork for a proof, not the finished product itself (and perhaps, how they'd go about turning it into the finished product).

Comment: Your writing it "in reverse" reminds me:
*I am discovering that mathematicians cannot tell the difference between “proof by contradiction” and “proof of negation”. This is so for good reasons, but conflation of different kinds of proofs is bad mental hygiene which leads to bad teaching practice and confusion.*

[Andrej Bauer](http://math.andrej.com/2010/03/29/proof-of-negation-and-proof-by-contradiction/)
Also this popular question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262828/using-proof-by-contradiction-vs-proof-of-the-contrapositive). (+1 BTW)

Comment: The only caution is that $A \Rightarrow B$ along with $B \Leftarrow C$ gives no conclusion between $A$ and $C$. In short the styles don't mix easy